# Out of memory error with Cipher.dofinal()

Tags: android, encryption, out-of-memory

I am developing an Android application for which I am **decrypting a large file using Cipher Class of Android.**

**Code:**

```
private byte[] decrypt_chunk(byte[] data, ByteString chunk_encryption_key) {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(chunk_encryption_key.toByteArray(), 1, 16, "AES");
        Cipher cipher;
        byte[] decrypted = new byte[0];
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(getIV(0)));

            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return decrypted;
    }
```

I am getting **"OutOfMemory"** error while decrypting large files.

I have following questions:

1. What chanegs in the current code can fix the **OOM error**?
2. Will **Cipher.update()** can help to fix the issue? If yes, how to implement it?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you load the data?

Comment: I am reading data from online servers and storing it in byte[].

Comment: You can't load the whole file at once. You need to load a block at a time.

Comment: The code is generating error when I am trying to decrypt the file but not when loading the file.

Comment: If you don't load as much data into m memory, the encryption algorithm will have more space to use.

Comment: The nonce (IV) must be unique (read: random) for CFB mode. Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Cipher.update() method is one possible way.

However in your case I recommend to you to use a [`CipherOutputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) instead. I assume you have an InputStream for retrieving the data from the server and an FileOutputStream for saving the data into a file.

Using the CipherOutputStream is pretty simple, just "wrap-it" around the FileOutputStream:

```
FileOutputStream fout = ...
CipherOutputStream cout = new CipherOutputStream(fout, cipher);
```

Now continue to use `cout` instead of `fout` and everything you write into it will be automatically encrypted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I need to perform some operations while reading bytes from the server and hence I am storing the data as byte[].

Comment: Or you use an `ChipherInputStream` instead (encryption/decryption while reading). It works the same way but wraps an InputStream like the one you get when loading a file from web.